# User form input fails to insert into database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

It's a Wordpress specific question.

[code here](https://github.com/1cookie/custom_reg_form/blob/master/designmodo-registration-form.php)

For some reason fields `title` `telno` & `foo` fail to get entered into the `wp_usermeta` database table. All other fields `username`, `email` etc do. Why? What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

`wp_insert_user` user accepts an array with specific keys. You cannot insert any other data. [(source)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user)

In order to add additional fields you should use a plugin or write one yourself.

Comment: what's the correct hook to insert usermeta information?